# Application of the Identity Theorem to $|x|^3$ for $-1<x<1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Oxford Exam $2602$ $1997$ $Q3$

We want to show that there is no function $f$ which is holomorphic in $D(0;1)$ and such that $f(x)=|x|^3$ for $-1<x<1$.

Here are my thoughts thus far:

Suppose there is. Then $g(x)=f(x)-|x|^3=0$ for $-1<x<1$. Then by the Identity Theorem we must have that $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ has a limit point in $S:=\{x:-1<x<1\}$.

I'm hoping this leads to a contradiction, but I can't see how. Perhaps the method is incorrect.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f(x)=|x|^3$ for $x\in (0,1)$, then $f(x)$ and $x^3$ agree on the interval $(0,1)$. Now use the identity theorem, and derive a contradiction.

**Edit:** For reference, my version of the identity theorem states:

If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are holomorphic functions on a domain $U$ (an open, path connected set), then if $\{ z \in U : f(z)=g(z)\}$ has a non-isolated point $w$, then $\forall z \in U,f(z)=g(z) $.

$\bigg($My definition of $w$ being a limit point for a set $S$ is that $\forall \epsilon > 0 , (B_\epsilon(w)\text{\ }\{w\})\cap S\not=\phi\bigg)$

Comment: @TomOlfield Thanks for your comment, but I can't see how a contradiction can be derived. $0$ is a limit point of $(0,1)$ so I guess we have that they have to agree at $0$. Is this going to help?

Comment: @Mathmo The identity theorem states that if the set of points that two functions (holomorphic and on a suitable domain) agree on has a non-isolated point, then they are equal. In this case, the set contains $(0,1)$ which consists entirely of non-isolated points! (I think I use the terminology "non-isolated point" where you use "limit point", for the record.)

Comment: Have we not just shown here though that they agree on $(0,1)$, where $|x|^3$ is equal to $x^3$ and is therefore differentiable everywhere and so holomorphic?

Comment: @Mathmo By Tom Oldfield's hint, $f(z)=z^3$ in $D(0,1)$. Contradiction when $z<0$.

Comment: @Mathmo, I don't think so, what we've shown is that they agree on a set with a non-isolated point, so by the identity theorem the two functions $f(z)$ and $z^3$ agree on the whole region in question. We can now derive a contradiction by other information we have about $f$.

Comment: @TomOldfield Right, can I just write out the logic here then so I make sure I understand how to apply the Identity Theorem. So we're saying that, as $f$ and $|x|^3$ agree on $(0,1)$, which contains a limit point of $S$, they agree on $S$. However, $f$ cannot agree with $|x|^3$ since it is not differentiable at $0$ and we require $f$ to be holomorphic on $D(0;1)$. Is this right?

Comment: @Mathmo Actually, we're saying that $f$ and the complex function $z^3$ agree on $(0,1)$. Every point in the set $(0,1)$ is a limit point of the set. Thus by the identity theorem (see the edit in my answer) the two functions $f(z)$ and $z^3$ agree on the whole disc. However, for $x\in (-1,0)$ we are given that $f(x)=|x|^3=-x^3$, contradicting the fact that we have already shown that $f(x)=x^3$ here (as $f(z)=z^3$ for all points $z$ in the disc). Would you like to discuss this further on chat?